# Comparing date with csh

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a way to compare the input date with current date if the input date has the following format?

`Sat Oct 10 00:00:55 2015`

Right now im checking if the month is not in `NOV, DEC` and the year is still `2015`.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Yes it is, check http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84381/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-a-shell  and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24626/quickly-calculate-date-differences

Answer (score 0):

The gnu corutils date command, standard under Linux, has a spiffy -d option that accepts a date in a variety of formats and then reformats it under the given string.

Convert your two dates into a format friendly for what you want:

```
set date_then_Y = "`date -d "$input_date" '+%Y'`";
set date_then_m = "`date -d "$input_date" '+%m'`";

eval "date '+set date_now_Y = '%Y'; set date_now_m = '%m';"
```

Now it is a matter of using the consistent variables to test what you want.

(have not run this, final debugging is left as an exercise to the student)